# Blockchain API whitelist all IP addresses

Tags: api, blockchain.info, blockchain-wallet-app

I am currently trying to implement the blockchain API in my application. I have done this successfully however, I am having trouble whitelisting IPs. Each time a user accesses the app with a different IP,they get an error. Therefore I have to manually approve that particular IP address. Honestly, this is a major pain. How can make it so that I do not have to approve each and every user's IP address? Is there a wildcard for all IP addresses in the world that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Use this: %.%.%.%

It mentions this in the IP Whitelist section, found in Account settings then IP Restrictions.

Comment: tried and didnt woked for me. got mail to authorize api access